# AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imresize' please how can i solve this?

Tags: python

Please please here is the line of code that returns an error to me: AttributeError: module 'scipy.misc' has no attribute 'imresize'

```
mask = np.reshape(binarized_predict_masks[j], newshape=(input_img_size, input_img_size))
resized_mask = scipy.misc.imresize(mask, size=(size, size), interp='nearest')/255.0
```

Here is the rest of the code

```
cropped_resized_mask = resized_mask[((size-w)//2):((size-w)//2 + w), 
                                                ((size-h)//2):((size-h)//2 + h)]
            cropped_resized_mask = np.reshape(cropped_resized_mask, newshape=(w, h, 1))

            predicted_mask_path = img_path.replace('original_2D', 'mask_original_2D', 2)

            # save txt file
            predicted_mask_txt_path = predicted_mask_path.replace('.png', '.txt', 1)
            np.savetxt(predicted_mask_txt_path, cropped_resized_mask, fmt='%.6f')

            # save image
            cropped_resized_mask_img = array_to_img(cropped_resized_mask,
                                                    data_format=None, 
                                                    scale=True)
            cropped_resized_mask_img.save(predicted_mask_path)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    predict_roi_net()
```

Please how can I solve this problem? thank you for any answer

Comment: You're trying to call a function that doesn't exist (`scipy.misc` doesn't have a function called `imresize` as the error message told you).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are trying to call a removed function.
The function `imresize` was removed in Scipy 1.3.0 as written in the documentation of the function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-1.2.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imresize.html.

Scipy propose to use Pillow to resize your image:

```
Image.fromarray(mask).resize((size, size))
```

Comment: thank you so much for answering me. I tried your line of code it seems to work. however at the next line of code I now receive the Error TypeError: 'Image' object is not subscriptable

Comment: that is the line

Comment: cropped_resized_mask = resized_mask[((size-w)//2):((size-w)//2 + w), 
                                                ((size-h)//2):((size-h)//2 + h)]
            cropped_resized_mask = np.reshape(cropped_resized_mask, newshape=(w, h, 1))

Comment: This is because, `resized_mask` is a Pillow object, and you would like to have a numpy array. You will have to transform it back into a numpy array. You can do that with: resized_mask  = np.array(resized_mask )